# Laminas hide errors on productive server

Tags: php, zend-framework, laminas

For my website, I use Laminas. I run it locally on a development server and on a public productive server. I want to hide errors to the public and only let them be visible on the dev server.
Therefore I wrote these lines into the public/index.php file:

```php
if(apache_getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')=='development'){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
}else{
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
}
```

I but error messages still get seen if `APPLICATION_ENV='productive'`.

---

I already checked wheter the server runs the *if code* or *else code*.

This question is not about handling an error, just to hide it's message to the public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to edit `config/autoload/local.php` on your production server

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_exceptions' => false
)
```

Comment: Didn't change the Errormessage: *An error occurred during execution; please try again later.* followed by the Stack trace.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to remove the cache (again)... I improved your suggestion and did:
`'display_exceptions' => (apache_getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')=='development')` so after removing the cache, it will take the settings given from apache.